# Tricky question involving trying to find $\Phi$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f\in C^2_0(\mathbb R)$, a compactly supported $C^2$ function on the real line. Therefore, for some $R > 0, f(x) = 0$ if $\vert x\vert > R$.
>
> 1. Derive an expression for $\Phi(x)$ such that $$u(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi(x - y)f(y)\,\mathrm dy$$ is a solution of $$\frac{\mathrm d^2 u}{\mathrm dx^2} = f(x), x\in \mathbb R.\tag{1}$$
> 2. Verify that $(1)$ is verified for this choice of $\Phi$.
> 3. Fix a typical value of $x$ and plot $\Phi(x - y)$ as a function of $y$.

How would go about starting this problem??? Do we differentiate the integral twice then solve for $\Phi$?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you hear about Green's function approach for solving an ODE? You can have a look at [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) and [Wolfram's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensFunction.html) pages.

In short, consider a linear operator $L$ (double derivative is linear), such that
$$
Lu=f
$$
Using Dirac delta function, we can write $f$ as follows (a convolution)
$$
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-s)f(s)\,\text{d}s
$$
We then argue that since $L$ is a linear operator, once we have the solution for
$$LG(x,s)=\delta(x-s) \tag{1}$$
we can obtain the solution for $Lu=f$ as follows (notice $G$ is a function of two variables in general).
$$
u(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(x,s)f(s)\,\text{d}s
$$
$G(x,s)$ depends on boundary conditions too because it itself is a solution of an ODE. In your question, $\Phi(x-y)$ is the Green's function. You just have to solve (1) with appropriate boundary conditions. My answer is very loose mathematically, but I hope you can now find relevant sources by yourself.